# TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useRef')

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, react-hook-form

I'm using Next.js, TypeScript, sanity and tailwindcss. Im trying to use the react-hook-form but i receive an error.

I've tried:

- changing the `Post` function to an arrow function
- changing the `Post` function to a const function
- changing the `IFormInput` interface to a type

This is where the error is:

```
  23 |      formState: { errors },
> 24 |  } = useForm<IFormInput>();
     |            ^
  25 | 
  26 |  return (
  27 |      <main>
```

And this is my code ([slug].tsx) in the **pages** folder:

```
import { useForm, SubmitHandler } from "react-hook-form";

interface IFormInput {
    _id: string;
    name: string;
    email: string;
    comment: string;
}

function Post({ post }: Props) {
 const { register, handleSubmit, formState: { errors } } = useForm<IFormInput>();

 return (
  <form>
   <input {...register("_id")} type="hidden" name="_id" value={post._id} />
   <input {...register("name", { required: true })} type="text"/>
   <input {...register("email", { required: true })} type="text" />
   <textarea {...register("comment", { required: true })} />            
   {errors.name && (<span>- The Name Field is required</span>)}
   {errors.comment && ( <span>- The Comment Field is required</span>)}
   {errors.email && ( <span>- The Email Field is required</span>)}
   <input type="submit" />
  </form>
 );
}
```

Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I had the same error bc I don't install 'React Hook Form' in the correct folder, make sure it is in your package.json

Answer (score 6):

I am putting this answer for them who recently started working with `Next.js 13`.

I faced this problem while using `react-hook-form` with `Next.js 13` release. I had following configuration:

```
const nextConfig = {
  experimental: {
    appDir: true,
  },
}
```

After changing the `appDir` value to `false`, the problem goes away.

Comment: youre a life saver for posting this after you figured it out.

Answer (score 3):

just verify your react-router-dom . i already installed it and my app was working perfectly but after some days i got this error so i verified my package.json and didnt find the react-router-dom dependency so try npm i react-router-dom again .

Answer (score 2):

First of all, look inside your `package.json` file to make sure every used library is listed either as `"dependencies"` or `devDependencies`. If not, install them individually.

For example, since you are using in your codebase `react-hook-form`, if you are not seeing it, open a terminal in the root folder of your project where `package.json` is, and run:

```
npm install react-hook-form
```

If the issue persists, make sure your Node.js version is not superior to the last [recommended](https://nodejs.org/en/) one. If not, downgrade it, and for that, you could use [n](https://www.npmjs.com/package/n) package from `npm`:

```bash
# Use the stable version of Node.js
npm i -g n
n stable
# If one of the above commands does not pass, you may need to use sudo:
sudo npm i -g n
sudo n stable
# Then delete node_modules and start over
rm -rf node_modules
npm install
```

Answer (score 2):

Solved this problem by removing node_modules + .next folders.
I installed the dependencies again + npm run dev and it worked.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Just wanted to add that I had this error and realized I was calling `useRef` outside of the component. Don't forget that you cannot call hooks outside of a functional component

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).