# Browser router is not rendering

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, web

I'm new to react and want to learn about browser routers but the browser router is not rendering

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom\client';
import { BrowserRouter,Route,Routes } from 'react-router-dom';
import Home from './pages/Home';


const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
    <BrowserRouter>
    <Routes>
    <Route index element={<Home/>}/>
    </Routes> 
  </BrowserRouter>


);
```

The Home component is perfectly rendering with react strict mode but it is not rendering with browser router
can someone explain why Iam getting this issue?

This is my Home.jsx file

```
import React from 'react'

export default function Home() 
{
  return (
    <div>Home</div>
  )
}
```

The error I'm getting :

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useRef')
    at useRef (react.development.js:1625:1)
    at BrowserRouter (index.tsx:151:1)
    at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:16305:1)
    at mountIndeterminateComponent (react-dom.development.js:20074:1)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:21587:1)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:27426:1)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:26557:1)
    at workLoopSync (react-dom.development.js:26466:1)
    at renderRootSync (react-dom.development.js:26434:1)
    at performSyncWorkOnRoot (react-dom.development.js:26085:1)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useRef')](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72567320/typeerror-cannot-read-properties-of-null-reading-useref)

Comment: @Fraser how is it related to react-router?

Answer (score 1):

You must specify the path prop to the `<Route>` component.

```
<Route index path="/" element={<Home/>}/>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Use BrowseRouter in index.js and wrap your App.

```
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
```

```
<BrowserRouter>
   <App />
</BrowserRouter>
```

and in App.js

```
import {Routes,Route} from "react-router-dom";
```

```
function App() {
  return (
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Home/>} />
        <Route path="/home" element={<Home/>} />
        <Route path="/about" element={<About />} />
       ... ...
      </Routes>
```